# shared_ptr creation after object creation

Tags: c++, heap-memory, shared-ptr, stack-memory

Is there a difference between:

```
Foo *foo = new Foo();
shared_ptr<Foo> sp(foo);
_fooVector.push_back(sp);
```

and

```
shared_ptr<Foo> sp(new Foo());
_fooVector.push_back(sp);
```

according to stack and heap. In all examples i can find `new` is used on the same line where the smart pointer get's created. So i'm wondering if the firs example is valid.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First example if valid, but it's more exception-safe and correct to use `make_shared`.

```
shared_ptr<Foo> sp = make_shared<Foo>();
```

In your first example - you allocate memory, initialize pointer with this memory, create shared_pointer (`shared_ptr` now owns memory) and then push copy to vector).
In second example - you allocate memory, initialize parameter of `shared_ptr` c-tor with this memory and then as in first example.

Comment: but what about the reference counter? will the memory be deallocated if the shared_ptr is destroyed,assuming the shared_ptr is declared in a scope lesser that that of the pointer,fo e.g within a block??

Comment: @Koushik yes. `shared_ptr` destructor will be called, reference-counter and pointer will be deleted and you will have dangling-pointer in code.

Comment: IS there an exception-safe way to create a shared pointer after an object is created?

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a difference [...] according to stack and heap

Both make the same use of the heap: one allocation for the `Foo` object, and one for the shared counter. <sub>(Assuming a typical implementation of `shared_ptr`)</sub>

In the first case, `foo` lasts until the end of the code block, while in the second the temporary pointer only lasts until the end of the declaration. So in principle, the second makes less use of the stack than the first; but in practice, both should be optimised to be (more or less) identical.

Better would be

```
_fooVector.push_back(std::make_shared<Foo>());
```

since that only needs to make a single heap allocation for both the `Foo` object and the shared count.

> So i'm wondering if the firs example is valid.

Yes, that's valid - you can initialise a shared pointer with any suitable pointer. It's slightly more dangerous for two reasons: the raw pointer is available to misuse, and it's possible to do something else before assigning it to the smart pointer, opening the possibility of a leak. Initialising directly from the `new` expression fixes the first danger, but not always the second. Using `make_shared` fixes both.

Answer (score -1):

from:http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr/

we have the third constructor allowed is:
from pointer (3) `template <class U> explicit shared_ptr (U* p);`

So yes, the first example is valid.

Comment: There is nothing different between the templates that would involve such a constructor.